# LabVIEW OOP: initializing parent from child

Tags: oop, inheritance, labview

#### Question

How do I set up my classes in LabVIEW so that I can keep all of the common data between different child classes in the parent class and still initialize that data from the `Initialize(data)` method of the child class?

#### Background

I have a fairly large project in which I am using LabVIEW object-oriented programming (LVOOP) tools to simplify some things. I have a class tree that looks something like this:

[image: representative class tree]

Ideally what I would like to do is to keep all of the data that is common between all of my *things* in the `GenericThing` class, but then initialize this data along with the class-specific data in unique `Initialize(data)` methods for `ThingType1` and `ThingType2`. Since the class-specific data is different between the two classes, and this data needs to be initialized, I cannot use the same signature for all of my `Initialize(data)` methods.

In Java I can do something like this:

```java
class abstract GenericThing {
  protected String name;
  public GenericThing(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class ThingType1 extends GenericThing {
  private int awesomeness;  // additional data
  public ThingType1(String name, int awesomeness) {
    super(name);
    this.awesomeness = awesomeness;
  }
}

class ThingType2 extends ThingType2 {
  private Boolean isSuperCool;  // different additional data
  public ThingType2(String name, Boolean isSuperCool) {
    super(name);
    this.isSuperCool = isSuperCool;
}
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do something similar in LabVIEW.

#### Attempts so far

I have tried to approach this from a couple of angles. First I tried creating an `Initialize(data)` dynamic dispatch method in my `GenericThing` class and then overriding it in the child classes, but this gives an error if you try to change the signature of the method (different inputs/outputs):

[image: fingerprint mismatch error]

OK, so I can't do it that way. Next I tried making data member access methods for the `GenericThing` class and calling them from the child class, but I cannot figure out how to call them in a way that actually sets data persistently. My attempt:

[image: Initialize method that does not work]

Basically using the `To More Generic Class` VI to get a reference to the parent class and set its data using the member access method that I created for `GenericThing`. This version runs just fine, but when I try to initialize both the parent and child data and then read that data back (similarly using `To More Generic Class` and my data member access method to read the parent's data), I get nothing for the parent's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out something that works while I was writing this, but this caused me enough of a headache that I didn't want to just abandon my post. I was almost there with the question. Basically when I initialize the `GenericThing` data in `ThingType1`'s `Initialize` method, I need to re-cast the output of `GenericThing`'s data member access method to a `ThingType1` object, initialize *its* data as well, and then pass that out like so (**Edit**: I do not need to recast this data. I can just directly pass the child-type reference into the parent-type method. Block diagrams updated below):

[image: Working Initialize method]

I can similarly pass the child-type reference directly to my parent-type method in the `Get Data` method:

[image: Working Get Data method]

And finally, I can initialize and read my data by calling these methods from a VI:

[image: Working test VI block diagram]

The result of running it with some random input values:

[image: Working test VI front panel]

Tadaa! Let me know if you have a better way of doing this.

#### Update

I updated my block diagrams based on some feedback in the comments. This makes one big improvement to my attempt at fixing my problem: I can directly wire the child's reference into the parent-type methods without dealing with the up-casting/down-casting syntax that was cluttering up my diagram!

Comment: You don't actually need to cast up and down. Because TT1 is a GT, you can wire it straight into the GT VI and because LV can see a clear in-out path for the object, the object coming out will still be TT1. This will simplify the code somewhat. It should be pointed out that this isn't essentially different from the super(name); line in the Java code. The key is to understand that the object is by-value, so you have to wire the modified object out.

Sidenote - I would highly recommend having all your I/O on the outer layer of the BD. This has both code readability and performance implications.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thanks! I thought that this way seemed a bit clunky. I will update my BD and post it here for anyone who might benefit from it in the future. What do you mean by having all of my I/O on the outer layer? As in you would not recommend initializing parent data in this way?

Comment: The outer layer only refers to the BD - it's the one which is not inside structures. Look at your Get Data VI as an example - what is the value of Name if there was an error in? It's ambiguous. Put the indicator outside the case and it's not.

I didn't notice that you're combining constructors. Be aware that adding the IO to the VIs of child classes doesn't scale (and, as you see, is clunky). You can just call the VI from the parent and then call another VI from the child on the same object to set the values. If you set the VIs to be accessors, you can use a property node for a simpler syntax.